# What SQL query to update from more than one table?

Tags: mysql

I use phpMyAdmin.
I want to update field where another table is related. I have tried the query but does not work. Here it is what I have tried

```
update tabel_a a set a.field='value' 
from tabel_a a, tabel_b b
where a.primary=b.foreign and b.field='value'
```

The question is why it is not work?
I want give a value where another field in another table have some value.
So I do this

```
where a.field=b.field and b.field='value'
```

anyone know about this?

Comment: add error message to your question. What is not working? What are you expecting? What is actually happened? More detail! We need more details!

Comment: You get error message ?

Comment: the query above is not working. what i want is update the value in child table where in case if the value in parent table has 'a' value (example)

Comment: it say eror from line 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `join`

```
Update tabel_a a join tabel_b b
on a.primary=b.foreign
set a.field='value' 
where b.field='value'
```

In MySQL, you can use the JOIN clauses in the UPDATE statement to perform cross-table update.

Comment: hey @Rahautos thankyou very much for your answer. that exactly what i mean :D

Comment: hey im sorry. why it is doesnt work. i was wrong. it is doesnt work. it dont change anything. it say 0 row affected while im prety sure that shouldnt be

Comment: Select * from  tabel_a a join tabel_b b
on a.primary=b.foreign
where b.field='value'

Comment: please check this query it select data or not ?@ErikMega

Comment: it is does select data but make the value of b.field has the same value of a.field.    it is confusing